# adding bing (with labels) maps to leaflet

Tags: leaflet, bing-maps

I am using this [leaflet plugin](https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins) to render bing aerial map as a base layer onto a leaflet map.

```
baseMapUrl = new L.BingLayer(bing_key);
map.addLayer(baseMapUrl);
```

But I am unable to find a way to render the bing maps with labels. [This post](http://alastaira.wordpress.com/2011/05/13/displaying-labels-on-top-of-bing-maps-custom-tile-layers/) describers some of the different bing map options, including "Aerial Map Style with labels"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking into the plugin there appears you can also pass in options when creating the key. One of the options is called "type" and is set to Aerial by default. That is Bing Maps without labels. To get labels you need to change this to AerialWithLabels. For example:

```
baseMapUrl = new L.BingLayer(bing_key, {type: 'AerialWithLabels'});
```

Comment: it's `AerialWithLabelsOnDemand` now. Ref: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701716.aspx